# "Infinite Sperner's Theorem"

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, order-theory

[Sperner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem) gives the size of a maximal antichain in $\mathcal{P}(X)$ where $X$ is a finite set.

In this, "antichain" means a set of mutually incomparable subsets (i.e. subsets such that for any two $A,B$ of them, neither $A\subseteq B$ nor $B\subseteq A$).

There must be a generalization of this to infinite sets: how is the cardinality of the maximal antichain in $\mathcal{P}(X)$ related to the cardinality of $X$? In particular, for infinite $|X|$, is it $2^{|X|}$? Is it a known statement? Is it perhaps trivial?

Comment: To clarify, by $\mathscr A$ being an antichain you mean that elements of $\mathscr A$ are pairwise incomparable?  There's also the notion of an antichain where elements are pairwise incompatible. In the latter case, you can bound $|\mathscr A|$ by $|X|$ (this is witnessed by any choice function for $\mathscr A$).

Comment: @Reveillark Correct, the same meaning as in (finite) Sperner's theorem.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If "$\mathscr A$ is an antichain" means $\forall A,B\in\mathscr A (A\neq B\to A\cap B=\emptyset)$, then any choice function $f:\mathscr A\to X$ must be injective. Or am I being dense?

Comment: @Reveillark Antichain means incomparability with respect to $\subseteq$, not disjointness.

Comment: @NoahSchweber In my initial comment I was asking whether "antichain" in this context meant pairwise incomparability, or pairwise disjointness.

Comment: @Reveillark I misread your comment, my apologies. But the OP did subsequently clarify that they mean the same as in the usual Sperner's theorem.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yeah OP clarified everything. No worries! I was starting to doubt my sanity.

Comment: I have edited this question just to add what I mean by "antichain" - I won't improve it any further. I asked it for pure curiosity. (Probably deservedly closed for no effort.) Thanks @NoahSchweber for your answer, anyways - much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the axiom of choice, if $X$ is infinite then $\mathcal{P}(X)$ has an antichain (with respect to inclusion) of size $2^{\vert X\vert}$ (which is obviously as large as possible).

Here's one way to prove this. For $A\subseteq X$, let $$\hat{A}=\{(x,1): x\in A\}\cup\{(x,0): x\not\in A\}.$$ Note that if $A$ and $B$ are distinct subsets of $X$, the sets $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ are inclusion-incomparable subsets of $X\times\{0,1\}$.

Now via the axiom of choice, since $X$ is infinite there is a bijection $f: X\times\{0,1\}\rightarrow X$. We use $f$ to "push through" the hat construction above to get a family of subsets of $X$. Specifically, for $A\subseteq X$ let $A'=\{f(i): i\in \hat{A}\}.$ It's easy to check that the family of subsets of $X$ $$\{A': A\subseteq X\}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$$ is an antichain with respect to $\subseteq$ and has cardinality $2^{\vert X\vert}$.